# TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc add (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, typeerror

I have a strange problem relating to a topic model I am running with BERTopic. The model runs without any errors in `Colab` and `vscode venv`. However, when I run the same model in `Jupyter Notebook` using the same `venv` as I have in the `vscode venv`, the model returns an error, half-way through the run.

The error is below:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\bertopic\_bertopic.py in fit_transform(self, documents, embeddings, y)
    285         # Reduce dimensionality with UMAP
    286         if self.seed_topic_list is not None and self.embedding_model is not None:
--> 287             y, embeddings = self._guided_topic_modeling(embeddings)
    288         umap_embeddings = self._reduce_dimensionality(embeddings, y)
    289 

c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\bertopic\_bertopic.py in _guided_topic_modeling(self, embeddings)
   1424         for seed_topic in range(len(seed_topic_list)):
   1425             indices = [index for index, topic in enumerate(y) if topic == seed_topic]
-> 1426             embeddings[indices] = np.average([embeddings[indices], seed_topic_embeddings[seed_topic]], weights=[3, 1])
   1427         return y, embeddings
   1428 

<__array_function__ internals> in average(*args, **kwargs)

c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py in average(a, axis, weights, returned)
    405             wgt = wgt.swapaxes(-1, axis)
    406 
--> 407         scl = wgt.sum(axis=axis, dtype=result_dtype)
    408         if np.any(scl == 0.0):
    409             raise ZeroDivisionError(

c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py in _sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial, where)
     45 def _sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False,
     46          initial=_NoValue, where=True):
---> 47     return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial, where)
     48 
     49 def _prod(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False,

TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc add
```

Not sure what the source of the error could be, since the same code works in `Colab` and `vscode venv`. Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is that all the error says?  Doesn't it specify the problem dtypes?

Comment: No, it does not specify the problem dtypes

Comment: I don't know anything about `bertopic`.  All I can recommend is that you review the function(s) signature/docs, and make sure your inputs match.  Pay particular attention to `dtype`.